# Duplicating objects using Animation Nodes' 'Grid Mesh' node

Tags: node-editor, animation-nodes

I'm trying to create an image similar to this.

[image: Sine wave image]

I can create the sine wave using nodes but I can't get them to repeat. I was following the tutorial https://youtu.be/o3N8H8X-GJk

My nodes are below and also the image it creates. I circled the node which seems to have changed from the tutorial. I'm using Blender 2.79b and Animation nodes 2.1.2

[image: My nodes]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to distribute a group of objects, you can use the *Distribute Matrices* node to generate the locations. You may also use the *Replicate Spline* node to ease things for yourself.

[image: Node Tree]